# the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not method

Tags: python, json, api, rest, python-requests

```py
response = requests.get(api).json
print(type(response))
data = json.loads(response)
```

I got `<class method>` and the error :
`JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not method`

can anyone help convert it into dict

Comment: There are two problems here: you need to call `.json()` instead of just looking at `.json`; and you need to use the result directly and not use the JSON library (that's why the `requests` library provides this method to you). This would be clear if you [read the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html). Literally the first thing on the web page is an example of doing this exact thing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `response = requests.get(api).json`, you're storing the `json` method itself in `response`, instead of calling the method and storing the *result* of that method call in `response`.

If you change it to `requests.get(api).json()` with the parentheses at the end, you'll call the method instead of just referring to it, and store the result in `response`.